# Script no me aplica cambios al xlsx

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

escribo porque estoy desarrollando un script para cribar registros repetidos en un excel con openpyxl. El script es según sigue:

```py
import openpyxl as xl

def main(file):
    wb = xl.load_workbook(file)
    sh = wb.active
    store = []
    for e in range(1, 1 + sh.max_row):
        store.append(sh["B" + str(e)].value)

    many = []
    for e in store:
        if many.count(e) < 1 < store.count(e):
            many.append(e)

    for e in range(1, 1 + sh.max_row):
        count = 0
        if many.count(sh["B" + str(e)].value) > 0 and count > 0:
            sh["J" + str(e)].value = "N"
        elif many.count(sh["B" + str(e)].value) > 0:
            count += 1

    wb.save(file.replace(".xlsx", "_act.xlsx"))
```

Lo que hace es: coge todos los valores posibles en la columna B, mira cuáles están repetidos (es decir, que están presentes más de una vez) y los separa (lo hace en una lista aparte, de ahí el A < 1 < B, puesto que quiero que el conteo del mismo en la lista separada sea menor que 1 y que el conteo en la lista de registros sea mayor a 1). Una vez tiene la lista aparte, mira registro a registro de la columna B si éste está presente en la lista de repetidas. Si lo está y no es la primera instancia del mismo, lo marca en la columna J con un "N" para poder separarlo vía excel después.

El caso es que, según lo ejecuto, me devuelve una copia del original (y se que es una copia porque me consta que existen registros repetidos en la columna B.

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estás reiniciando `count` a 0 en cada iteración del ciclo, por lo que `count` nunca es mayor de 0 cuando se llega la primer condicional. De cualquier forma, dado que los valores repetidos no han de estar en principio contiguos, necesitarías tener un contador por cada valor repetido.

No obstante, si he entendido lo que deseas, es mucho más simple y eficiente si usas un conjunto para almacenar los valores ya encontrados y detectar así los repetidos:

```
import openpyxl as xl



def main(file):
    wb = xl.load_workbook(file)
    sh = wb.active

    vistos = set()

    for cell in sh['B']:
        if cell.value in vistos:
            sh["J" + str(cell.row)].value = "N"
        else:
            vistos.add(cell.value)

    wb.save(file.replace(".xlsx", "_act.xlsx"))
```

Simplemente iteramos sobre la columna, si el valor no ha sido visto antes (no existe en el conjunto) lo agregamos al conjunto, si ha sido visto antes es un valor repetido y no es la primera vez que aparece por lo que lo marcamos con la `"N"` en la columna J. La razón de usar un conjunto y no una lista por ejemplo es porque las búsquedas en conjuntos son mucho más eficientes al usar tablas hash y contener solo valores únicos.

El resultado, a modo de ejemplo, es algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Un par de observaciones:

- Cuando quieras saber si un item cualquiera está presente o no al menos una vez en un iterable (incluida una lista) no hagas:

  ```
  if lista.count(item) > 0
  ```

  usa el operador de pertenencia `in` / `not in`:

  ```
  if item in lista
  ```

  hay muchas razones, entre ellas la legibilidad, pero principalmente la eficiencia, `count` obliga a recorrer la lista al completo siempre y a llevar una cuenta de las apariciones mientras que `in` en el momento que encuentra el item retorna.
- Cuando quieras contar las veces que los items aparecen en un iterable, usa [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), es mucho más eficiente y simple que complicarte la vida con una lista y `list.count`:

  ```
  import collections
  iterable = ["a", "b", "f", "a", "a", "f", "j"]
  cont = collections.Counter(iterable)
  ```

  > ```
  > >>> cont    
  > Counter({'a': 3, 'f': 2, 'b': 1, 'j': 1})    
  >
  > >>> cont["a"])    
  > 3
  > ```
- Si solo quieres obtener los valores únicos (sin repeticiones) de un iterable sin que te importe el orden usa un conjunto:

  > ```
  > >>> iterable = ["a", "b", "f", "a", "a", "f", "j"]
  > >>> unicos = set(iterable)
  > >>> unicos
  > {'f', 'b', 'j', 'a'}
  > ```

  si te importa el orden usa un diccionario (Python >= 3.7) o `collections.OrderedDict` en versiones anteriores:

  > ```
  > >>> iterable = ["a", "b", "f", "a", "a", "f", "j"]
  > >>> unicos = dict.fromkeys(iterable).keys()
  > >>> unicos
  > dict_keys(['a', 'b', 'f', 'j'])
  > >>> "a" in unicos
  > True
  > >>> "x" in unicos
  > False
  > >>> list(unicos)
  > ['a', 'b', 'f', 'j']
  > ```